# AS3 Best practices for a method that could return two types

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, types, wildcard, return-type

I've been developing a framework for ActionScript 3 and have come across a peculiar scenario where I want a method to be able to return either an `AvFrameworkObject` or an `Array` containing multiple instances of `AvFrameworkObject`.

Take this method which is used to register one or more instances of `AvFrameworkObject`:

```
public function register(...objects):Object
{
    var reg:Array = [];

    var i:AvFrameworkObject;
    for each(i in objects)
    {
        i.fw = this;
        reg.push(i);
    }

    return reg.length > 1 ? reg : reg[0];
}
```

A few things on the above:

1. This seems extremely sloppy to me. Is it really?
2. I could use a wildcard (asterisk *) as the return type as well, which makes more sense?
3. Is it possible to actually define **two return types only**? Just for the sake of readability etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, all objects are passed [by reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f56.html):

> In ActionScript 3.0, all arguments are passed by reference, because all values are stored as objects. However, objects that belong to the primitive data types, which includes Boolean, Number, int, uint, and String, have special operators that make them behave as if they were passed by value.

You don't have to return anything, just setting the `fw` variable member will work.

---

That being said, you have some options on how to return multiple variables.

- A common approach is to return the count of the array returned, and use an argument to set the array. A call would be like `var length:int = register(out, object1, object2, object3)`. Then you can use the `length` variable in a for loop.
- Another approach is to return the entire array. I think it doesn't need more explanation, but I want to make it clear that you can use the returned array directly, if you want a specific member. For example, if you want the first object, you can write `t:Thing = fw.register(new Thing())[0];`. Take note of the **[0]** at the end.
- You can also use above methods but using `Object` insted of `Array`.

Personally I don't prefer to return an abstract object, normally I choose to return the entire array.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

1. In some strict sense yea this can be sloppy but I've seen much worse.
2. You should always have the return type as narrow as you can. So a * as a return type is worse IMO than Object.
3. No you can not have two return types.

If you have good tests around it and document it well then it can be ok to use.

But how about you always return an array, if there is only 1 result, then you return an array of size 1?

Comment: @Marty Wallace: Or even return Vector.<AvFrameworkObject> of size 1 or 2 to be even more typed (if you can use Vector in your project.)

Comment: what's the difference between returning * and returning Object?

Comment: Returning an Array of length 1 was the way I had it set up initially, just seems cleaner if I were to go var t:Thing = fw.register(new Thing()); t.property = "blah";

Comment: looking at your code: I would suggest returning a Vector<T>. After all - imagine writing the client code in which a function may return an unknown type of object. You would have to check for its type on every call. Tedious. Better to return a Vector each time.You're not saving anyone trouble by returning a second type just because its a vector with one member.

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 check out this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103377/actionscript-variable-declared-as-star-type

Answer (score 0):

Personally in this case I would return the 1 item array for consistency. That will make for a much more sensible interface; the caller can always expect to be returned an array, rather than having to make the code more convoluted by responding differently to different returned objects.

Now there is also the situation where the code will respond in exactly the same way to the returned object no matter what it's type is, in which case that means the returned objects inherited from some common base class. In that case the return type should be the common base class.

(I suppose I'm assuming here that you won't respond in exactly the same way to an Array and an AvFrameworkObject)

Comment: The point of the function being able to return a single AvFrameworkObject is that I can then go: var obj:AvFrameworkObject = fw.register(new AvFrameworkObject()); Then, if I wanted to register multiple instances at once I could but the single return didn't make sense if this were the case. Maybe I should split the function into register():AvFrameworkObject and registerMultiple():Array. What do you think?